# $(x,y,1)$ is perpendicular to $(1,2,-7)$. What is the relationship between $x$ and $y$?

Tags: vectors

> $(x,y,1)$ is perpendicular to $(1,2,-7)$. What is the relationship between $x$ and $y$?

I think that there is no relationship between $x$ and $y$ because they could be any number. I know that the dot product of both $x$ and $y$ must be $0$ but that hasn't helped me get anywhere.

Comment: The dot product of the vectors is $0$, so $x+2y=7$. That is a relationship in my eyes.

Comment: Presumably, $x$ and $y$ are scalars, not vectors---what is the dot product of $x$ and $y$ then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two non-null vectors $u,v$, they are orthogonal ("perpendicular") if and only if
$$u\cdot v=0.$$

So given $(x,y,1)$ and $(1,2,-7)$, that gives us the equation:
$$(x,y,1)\cdot (1,2,-7) = x + 2y -7=0$$
So the relationship between $x$ and $y$ is
$$\boxed{x=7-2y}$$